# Check if a class is generic type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Maybe this is not a big problem, but i could not figure it out. Is there a way to check if a class is defined as a generic type. I don't want to define an instance of this class, i just want somehow to know, if this class is defined as a normal class or as generic type class.

This would be the first Class, which is of type Generic

```
public class MyGenericClass<T, G> {

    public void someMethod(T firstParam, G secondParam){
        // do something
    }
}
```

and this would be the second and normal Class

```
public class AnotherClass {

   public void someMethod(){
       // do something
   }
}
```

I want a way to find out this result

```
isGenericType(MyGenericClass.class) --> true
isGenericType(AnotherClass.class) --> false
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you don't mean to instantiate this class, how would you ever think of using it?

Comment: From the `Class<?>` object you can check `cls.getTypeParameters()`

Comment: I am working with java reflections and am interested in its methods. I just want to get the normal classes and get their methods and filter out the generic type classes. That’s why I don’t need to instantiate this class.

Comment: If `firstParam` is an instance of, say, `class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {}`, is that generic or not?

Comment: thanks to @khelwood. It actually works, and i get a array of generic types for generic type classes and array of length 0, for non-generic type classes.

Comment: @AndyTurner: According to what I remember from the spec, `StringList` in your sample is not a generic class anymore/has never been one. But as it implements/extends a generic class, the OP's use case may still want to recognise it as generic. But that needs to be explained by the OP itself.

Comment: @tquadrat yes. That's why I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `Class<?> object` you can check [`cls.getTypeParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters--).

From a generic class you get a nonempty array of `TypeVariable`.

From a non-generic class you get an empty array.

E.g.

```
java.util.List.class.getTypeParameters()
TypeVariable[1] { E }
```

```
String.class.getTypeParameters()
TypeVariable[0] {}
```